# Creating a simple calculator that manipulates innerHTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, this, getelementbyid

I'm trying to make a simple weight and balance calculator for an airplane. The requirements are simple, I need to enter a weight and have a moment field updated to contain the weight multiplied by the known moment arm.  Basically, I just need to multiply an input by a known value and have this product printed into another space.

Below is what I've tried so far, and it is supposed to work by:

1. Passing the value of the input dialogue using `this.value` on an `onchange` event
2. Find the output element uisng `document.getElementById(outID)`
3. Set the output element text using `outID.innerHTML = weight*arm`

However, nothing ever happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function GetMoment(outID,weight,arm){
            var outputObj = document.getElementById( outID );
            outputObj.innerHTML = weight*arm;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<html>
<body>
<div id="InputForm" style="width:600;float:left;">
<table name="WeightAndBalance" border=4>
    <tr>
        <th>Front Seats</th>
        <th> <input id="FrontWeight" type="text" name="FrontWeight" onchange="javascript:GetMoment(FrontMoment,this.value,85.5)"> </th>
        <th>85.5 in</th>
        <th> <span id="FrontMoment" type="text" name="FrontMoment" style="width:50px">Front Seat Moment</span></th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Rear Seats</th>
        <th> <input id="RearWeight" type="text" name="RearWeight" onchange="javascript:GetMoment(RearMoment,this.value,117)"> </th>
        <th>117 in</th>
        <th> <span id="RearMoment" type="text" name="RearMoment">Rear Seat Moment</span></th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
GetMoment(RearMoment,this.value,117)
```

to this form:

```
GetMoment('RearMoment',this.value,117)
```

each place that it occurs.  An id is a string.

---

Also, `javascript:` is pretty old school - no need for it.  It can just be like this:

```
<input id="RearWeight" type="text" name="RearWeight" onchange="GetMoment('RearMoment',this.value,117)">
```

Comment: should be 'ReadMoment' no "ReadMoment" since the double quote is used in the HTML.